# how to set axis interval in candle stick using pyqtgraph with pyqt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am using pyqtgraph to draw a candle stick like the following:

```
#-------------------
# Create pyqtgraph module 
#------------------- 
def GUI_DRAW_create():
    """
    set default config
    """
    pg.setConfigOption('background', 'w')   #background: white
    pg.setConfigOption('foreground', 'k')   #font: black

class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        #values is not my date in timestamp 
        return [datetime.fromtimestamp(value) for value in values]
    
## Create a subclass of GraphicsObject.
## The only required methods are paint() and boundingRect() 
## (see QGraphicsItem documentation)
class CandlestickItem(pg.GraphicsObject):
    def __init__(self, data):
        pg.GraphicsObject.__init__(self)
        self.data = data  ## data must have fields: time, open, close, min, max
        self.generatePicture()
    
    def generatePicture(self):
        ## pre-computing a QPicture object allows paint() to run much more quickly, 
        ## rather than re-drawing the shapes every time.
        self.picture = QtGui.QPicture()
        p = QtGui.QPainter(self.picture)
        p.setPen(pg.mkPen('k'))
        w = (self.data[1][0] - self.data[0][0]) / 3.
        for (t, open, close, min, max) in self.data:
            p.drawLine(QtCore.QPointF(t, min), QtCore.QPointF(t, max))
            if open > close:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('r'))
            else:
                p.setBrush(pg.mkBrush('g'))
            p.drawRect(QtCore.QRectF(t-w, open, w*2, close-open))
        p.end()
        # I try to print out t here, is my date 
    def paint(self, p, *args):
        p.drawPicture(0, 0, self.picture)
    
    def boundingRect(self):
        ## boundingRect _must_ indicate the entire area that will be drawn on
        ## or else we will get artifacts and possibly crashing.
        ## (in this case, QPicture does all the work of computing the bouning rect for us)
        return QtCore.QRectF(self.picture.boundingRect())
        
        
class GUI_DRAW_new(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        GUI_DRAW_create()
        
        self.setWindowTitle("pyqtgraph example: PlotWidget")
        
        cw = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(cw)
        
        main_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        cw.setLayout(main_layout)
        
        #variable 
        self.signalgraph = None
        self.data = []
        self.vb = None
        self.vLine = None
        
        # define plot windows
        self.GUI_DRAW_new_graph()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.signalgraph)
        
        self.signalgraph.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.signalgraph.viewport().installEventFilter(self)
        
        self.show()

    def eventFilter(self, source, event):
        try:
            if (event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove and
                source is self.signalgraph.viewport()):
                pos = event.pos()
                print('mouse move: (%d, %d)' % (pos.x(), pos.y()))
                if self.signalgraph.sceneBoundingRect().contains(pos):
                    mousePoint = self.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
                    index = int(mousePoint.x())
                    int(index)
                    #if index > 0 and index < len(self.data):
                        #print(self.xdict[index])
                        
                    #    self.label.setHtml("<p style='color:black'>日期：{0}</p>".format(self.data[index]))
                    #    self.label.setPos(mousePoint.x(),mousePoint.y())
                    self.vLine.setPos(mousePoint.x())
                    
            return QtGui.QWidget.eventFilter(self, source, event)
        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            err = sys.exc_info()[1]
            PRINT_DEBUG(0,str(err))
            
    def GUI_DRAW_new_graph(self):
        try:
            self.signalgraph = pg.PlotWidget(name="Signalgraph", axisItems={'bottom': TimeAxisItem(orientation='bottom')})
            
            # sample data
            self.data = [  ## fields are (time, open, close, min, max).
                (1514995200.0, 102.610001, 105.349998, 102, 105.370003),
                (1515081600.0, 105.75, 102.709999, 102.410004, 105.849998),
                (1515168000.0, 100.559998, 102.370003, 99.870003, 100.699997),
                (1515254400.0, 98.68, 96.449997, 96.43, 100.129997),
                (1515340800.0, 98.550003, 96.959999, 96.760002, 99.110001),
                
                (1515427200.0, 102.610001, 105.349998, 102, 105.370003),
                (1515513600.0, 105.75, 102.709999, 102.410004, 105.849998),
                (1515600000.0, 100.559998, 102.370003, 99.870003, 100.699997),
                (1515686400.0, 98.68, 96.449997, 96.43, 100.129997),
                (1515772800.0, 98.550003, 96.959999, 96.760002, 99.110001),
            ]
            
            #if comment this 2 code, can see the string
            item = CandlestickItem(self.data)
            self.signalgraph.addItem(item)
            
            #trick
            s_day = datetime.fromtimestamp(self.data[0][0]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            e_day = datetime.fromtimestamp(self.data[len(self.data) - 1][0]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            tr=np.arange(s_day, e_day, dtype='datetime64') # tick labels one day 
            
            tday0=(tr-tr[0])/(tr[-1]-tr[0])  #Map time to 0.0-1.0 day 2 1.0-2.0 ...
            tday1=tday0+1
        
            tnorm=np.concatenate([tday0,tday1])
            tr[-1]=tr[0]  # End day=start next day
            
            ttick=list()    
            for i,t in enumerate(np.concatenate([tr,tr])):
                tstr=np.datetime64(t).astype(datetime)
                ttick.append(  (tnorm[i],  tstr.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")))  
        
            ax=self.signalgraph.getAxis('bottom')    #This is the trick  
            ax.setTicks([ttick])
            #cross hair in signalgraph
            self.vLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=90, movable=False)
            self.signalgraph.addItem(self.vLine, ignoreBounds=True)
            self.vb = self.signalgraph.plotItem.vb
            
        except Exception as e:
            traceback.print_exc()
            err = sys.exc_info()[1]
            print(0,str(err))
                        

# Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    gui = GUI_DRAW_new()
    app.exec_()
```

The result is:

candlestick_graph_center

[image]

I want to set the x-axis interval using the date: [2018-01-04, 2018-01-05, 2018-01-06, ....].
Thanks for help, many thanks

## Update

I figure out that why all data squeeze together, because of the `TextItem`.
So that, I rewrite the code.

I try to use `tickStrings` in `AxisItem` to convert value to string, when I print out the `values` in `tickStrings`, it is not my data value (date in timestamp). Why the values are different? Thanks a lots

## Update

If I use `setTicks` with candle stick, it cannot show string in the graph. Only can show the string without candle stick.
Any idea?
[image]

Comment: How do you get the second image?

Comment: @eyllanesc using same code

Comment: I get the first image, not the second.

Comment: @eyllanesc finally find that the `TextItem` cannot show correctly, after remove it, it will make everything normal

Comment: But I still cannot set the date interval in x-axis

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert into a string with the appropriate format using [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime):

```
from datetime import datetime

class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        #values is not my date in timestamp 
        return [datetime.fromtimestamp(value).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for value in values]
```

Or:

```
from datetime import date

class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        #values is not my date in timestamp 
        return [date.fromtimestamp(value) for value in values]
```

Or:

```
from datetime import datetime

class TimeAxisItem(pg.AxisItem):
    def tickStrings(self, values, scale, spacing):
        #values is not my date in timestamp 
        return [datetime.fromtimestamp(value).date() for value in values]
```

[image]

Comment: Yap, but the data cannot show exactly. The first datetime is 2018-01-04 00:00:00, 2018-01-05 00:00:00, ....
It seems the values get wrong in `tickStrings`

Comment: @shadowdk 
That's because of the space they occupy, pyqtgraph handles whether or not it appears using the size as a reference. Well, I'll look for a way to make them permanent.